# PHP not connection to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my PHP pages to connection to a remote server hosting the MySQL database. I can connect via the command line just fine with the same username and password. Below is a simple test file I created. The only thing I've done to the code is remove the password, but I know that's not the issue. Like I said I can connect via the CLI. This is a Linux install. When viewed from the web browser, all I get is an error 500 page. If I comment out the mysqli statement, the page displays the Connected successfully.

```
<?php

$servername = "12.0.1.170";
$username = "jason";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {
/   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: php mysqli extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php wont connect to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345532/php-wont-connect-to-mysql)

Comment: I would turn up the logging level and see what its says

Comment: Add database in the call to mysqli_connect()

Comment: After doing some more searching I think it's something about the extension. I edited the php.ini file and removed the comment on extension=msql.so. I restarted the httpd service but it still doesn't appear to be loaded when i view the phpinfo()

Comment: API Extensions mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql
that is listed in my phpinfo page

Comment: On the right track now. Had to install php-mysqlnd at least now I get an error message instead of just a 500 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the **[php](/questions/tagged/php)** documentation for [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

Your code appears to be lacking all four parameters required.

You have:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

Perhaps try:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

with a `$database='db_name';` value added into your variables section.

Comment: I will try adding the db name

Comment: Still have the same issue.

Comment: I've taken your code and tested it, I get the same result, just the error 500 page.

Comment: Okie, time for error reporting...

Add these two lines of code at the very top of the page, just below the opening php tag

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Response now...

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/test2.php on line 3
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002 Debugging error: Connection refused

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Comment: Hey, sure thing. What did line 3 end up being? What did you do to get it resolved?

Comment: That was a typo in the DB name. Matter of case sensitivity. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues with remote mysql connection:

**1. Firewall of the server**: You must enable incoming connection on port (for. e.g. 3306).

**2. User in mysql**: You must have a user created (for e.g. jason in this case)

Comment: I know it's not a firewall issue and the account is correct. I can connect to it via the command line. I do appreciate the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting this way

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_name');
if($con)
echo "hell yeah its connected";
else
echo "i m boned"
```